# Why couldn't I see data committed to Postgres database from spring hibernate program?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql

I am trying to program using spring, JPAhibernate, and Postgres. There is no error running the program, and it successfully inserted data showing from client browser. However, Postgres database says relation "person" does not exist (My table name is "person"), which I think it means data is not committed to database. I tried

1. clean browser cache, and restart server. But program can still retrieve correct items. It looks like they are stored in the database.
2. set the hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto to be "validate" or "create-drop" or "update". But I can't see updated data in the database, even the table "person" doesn't exist.

Can anyone explain me why it's like this, or how can I see committed data in the database? Thank you.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain you're connecting to *the same database* from Hibernate and via your other client (psql/pgadmin/whatever)?

Comment: Can you put the exact error from postgres please "Postgres database says relation "person" does not exist". Is this a new app or you have created entity for existing app? Are the other entities getting persisted in DB successfully ? please elaborate.
Please share your persistence.xml as well.

Comment: You're right, it's my mistake. I didn't access the right database. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common cause for this sort of thing is connecting to a different database, or a database of the same name on a different host/port, than you think you are. So you're not really modifying the same thing you are looking at.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
```

you can set hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update to update your database with changes to your model

Comment: You have JPA entities?can you please post your config files and person class?your tables are being  created from jpa entities ?